# Parsing Wordpress API JSON with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, wordpress, cordova

i have following output from Wordpress API JSON and want to parse it with AngularJS:

```
attachments: [
    {
        id: 241740,
        url: "url/1.jpg",
        slug: "slug-from-title",
        title: "Slug from Title",
        description: "",
        caption: "",
        parent: 241738,
        mime_type: "image/jpeg",
        images: {
            full: {
                url: "url/1.jpg",
                width: 770,
                height: 400
            },
            thumbnail: {
                url: "url/1-150x150.jpg",
                width: 150,
                height: 150
            },
            medium: {
                url: "url/1-300x156.jpg",
                width: 300,
                height: 156
            },
            post-thumbnail: {
                url: "url/1-615x400.jpg",
                width: 615,
                height: 400
            }
        }
    }
],
thumbnail_images: {
    full: {
        url: "url/1.jpg",
        width: 770,
        height: 400
    },
    thumbnail: {
        url: "url/1-150x150.jpg",
        width: 150,
        height: 150
    },
    medium: {
        url: "url/1-300x156.jpg",
        width: 300,
        height: 156
    },
    post-thumbnail: {
        url: "url/1-615x400.jpg",
        width: 615,
        height: 400
    }
}
```

If i try to parse it in Phonegap with AngularJS and take:

```
post.attachments[0].images.thumbnail.url
```

it returns the URL i need, but:

```
post.thumbnail_images.medium.url
```

returns nothing.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't see a `medium-thumb` property anywhere? You can try `post.thumbnail_images.medium.url`

Comment: It was a typo. I corrected but it doesnt show anything